# CollectionViewSource Sorting Dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, collectionviewsource

I have a Car class with various properties.

I have a static Cars collection class in which, for simplicity, I have defined a bunch of car items which I can make available in XAML via an object data provider.

I have a collection view source defined in XAML which binds successfully to my ObjectDataProvider as it should.

I have a listbox which shows the collection.

I added the sort to the CVS as recommended in all the standard tutorials and all works fine.

My Question:
Suppose I want to sort on a different field. Surely there is a way to change this without having to give the code to the customer. So I implemented a combo box.

I use the following code to load a list of properties from the Car class into the combo box but I don’t just get a list of properties. I also get their data types. I don’t want this.

```
Car xyz=new Car(); //Make a temp Car Object so we can get a list of properties.
//Assign this to the combobox for listing.
cbxSortPrimary.ItemsSource = xyz.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Result (what displays in the combo box):

```
System.String Model
Double Price
Int32 NoOfPrevOwners
DataType PropertyName
ect... ect...
ect... ect...
ect... ect...
```

My goal is to load in the property names to the combo box. Then use the selected property name to build a line of code like:

```
myListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Where the ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() will contain the name of the property to be sorted on.

So **how do I get rid of the data type in front of the property name**. *I know I can do all sorts of messy loading into another list, then a bunch of string handling looking for the first space from the right and chopping everything before that*. **But surely there must be an easier way.**

Effectively what I am looking to do is to let the user sort on a different property of the Car class (So I need to load the properties somewhere and make them available for the user to select, hence the combobox). What I am asking is that there must be an easy way to get the list of properties without all the string manipulation code, and hopefully without much reflection (unless I am already using it without knowing), as it seems like a very basic requirement.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not messy at all:

```
        var properties = new List<string>();

        foreach (var info in typeof(Car).GetProperties())
        {
            properties.Add(info.Name);
        }
        cbxSortPrimary.ItemsSource = properties;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution and for the fast response. Well done.